# Naming guidelines with C#

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, hungarian-notation

I have this class:

```
class DoSomething
{
    private int timesDone;
    ...
}
```

Which is the right way to named variable 'timesDone'?

Sometimes I see named as **m_timesDone**. Is this correct? Where I can find information about naming guidelines?

Thank you!

Comment: m_, s_, etc. are discouraged for public members by the guidelines cedrou pointed you to. I don't think the official guidelines say anything about private fields. I usually just use `timesDone` for private fields and `TimesDone` for the exposing property. When I'm setting the field in a constructor, I call the parameter `timesDone` and refer to the field as `this.timesDone`. I find `_timesDone` for the field, `timesDone` for the parameter and `TimesDone` for the property an acceptable combination as well. But this is all just my opinion. You should form your own. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MS standards your code is OK. Having prefixes as m_ is not really necessary when you have advanced IDE. However short prefix like **_** can be used to take advantage of auto complete feature to quickly sort out class members.

I would recommend you to get a copy of "[Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)" book to learn more on MS standards

Comment: the m_ or _ or whatever is necessary if you don't feel like prefacing each variable with 'this'

Comment: @EdSwangren, it is very unusual situation when you have to use "this." construction. if you are using descriptive names you will find that the only place you need it (but not required to) is constructor

Comment: Yep - MS does not have guidelines for private fields. We use underscore. Definitely get Framework Design Guidelines - note that there is a second edition: http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613

Comment: I'm reading this book now and it said that all identifiers uses Pascal notation except parameters that use camel notation. I haven't see anything about private fields.

Comment: @aku: I don't agree.  Say I have a private instance field name, and a constructor which takes a parameter "name", or a method, etc.  I would run into it all of the time if I used that convention.

Comment: Though I suppose that, in that case, "name" would probably be a public property, i.e., "Name", so it would not clash.  Bad example :)

Comment: StyleCop warns against Hungarian notation and using variables with an underscore at the beginning

Comment: @aku, additionally, StyleCop recommends using this as a qualifier everywhere applicable.  It does help in the regard if instantly determining that something is scoped to the class, as opposed to an individual method.  More stylistic opinion than anything concrete, though.

Answer (score 5):

There is no universal right way. Chose a naming convention of your liking and stick with it.

Comment: Or, better yet, use one to the liking of your entire team.  Standards should be a collaborative effort and not a one person dictation - unless you are the only person on the team, that is.

Comment: I totally agree. Also you should look around for examples of good conventions just so you don't have to make some silly mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely do not use m_timesDone.

Simply put "private int timesDone".

You can learn about how to name variables by reading some good books such as Code Complete.

Comment: Uh...why not?  Sounds a bit dogmatic to me, -1

Comment: It's against the coding guidelines.  It isn't the way C# is written.  Just like you don't start methods out with lowercase letters.

Comment: It's personal/company preference, really.  Private fields are an irrelevance when it comes to the public API so using (or not using them) isn't going to go against .NET standards IMO.

Comment: AFAIK the guidlines don't say anything about *private* stuff. I personally prefer `_privateField`, because then I can have ctor parameters named `privateField` and you can immediately see the difference between a local variable and an instance field.

Answer (score 3):

Many people do as you have it there.  You would then reference it as

```
this.timesDone = someInt
```

However, I don't like this because I am not a fan of typing 'this' to avoid clashes with method parameter names.  As long as it is readable and consistent you will be fine.

Comment: +1 - THANK you! I got hammered on another thread for daring to say that you don't need "this" most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

The convention of prefacing member fields with m_ comes from the early days of C++, when [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) was popular. It is not a C# convention, and since most C# code is written using a recent Visual Studio it adds visual noise without any corresponding advantage, because you can easily see the scope of a variable anyway. Do not use m_.

The lone example of Hungarian notation that has found its way into C# is the practice of prefacing interface class names with I, such as IDisposable.

Comment: Many people also habitually start type parameters with T, which is somewhat Hungarianesque.

Comment: @Eric, is that something to be avoided in your opinion? Isn't this what MS does too in the BCL?

Answer (score 2):

You can find some information directly on the MSDN site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: Of course, they do not seem to specify a casing convention for private instance variables :)

Answer (score 1):

The only point of agreement that you will find is that it should ***not*** be TimesDown, but that it should start with a lower case letter.
In older publications (MS, MSDN), the use of a leading underscore is discouraged. Later it is back, especially for backingfields for properties: _timesDown.

Answer (score 0):

The Strategy usually adopted is :

For **Class** & **Method**: ***Pascal Casing***

e.g.

```
public class Program
 {
 }
```

e.g

```
public void DoSomething() { }
```

For **Variables**: ***Camel Casing*** e.g. timesDown

*Local Variables:*

```
   aTimesDown
```

*Global Variable:*

```
myTimesDown
```

I hope this may help you :)

Comment: **NB** These apply to public/protected members and public non-member classes. There is no guidance on private members.